# Antiderivative of an even function

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

I'm faced with an issue in terms of antiderivatives of even and odd functions.

Define $f \in C[-a,a]$ where $a>0$. Let $f$ be an even function on $[-a,a]$.

We wish to show that

$$\int_{-a}^a f(x)\ dx = 2\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\ dx$$

On the whole, I understand how to manipulate integrals and their substitution to get this result. However, I am faced with another alternative proof, where we define
$$F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\ dt.$$

for $-a \leq x \leq a$, and it is easy to show that $F(-x)=-F(x)$, and so the proof can also proceed along these lines.

However, with a different definition of $F$, i.e.

$$F(x)=\int_{-a}^x f(t)\ dt,$$

I fail to be able to obtain the result.
So my question is, why does the first definition of $F$ work, and why does the second fail?

I hope to gain more understanding of even and odd functions from this.

Comment: $F$ from the second definition is not an even function.

Comment: You mean it's not odd?

Comment: Choosing lower (or upper) limit $0$ is symmetry-preserving.

Comment: @ireallydonknow If $f$ is an even function, then in general $F$ is neither even nor odd. Consider $f(x)=x^2$ on $[-1,1]$. Then $F(x)=\int_{-1}^{x} t^2\, dt=\frac{1}{3}(x^3+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt failed because F (in second definition) no need to be either even or odd although $f$ is an even fuction on $[-a,a]$. As an example consider the  continuous function $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ define by $f(x)=1$ for each $x\in [-1,1]$. Then clearly f is even.

Observe that $$ F(x)=\int_{-1}^{x}f(t)dt=\int_{-1}^{x}1dt=x+1 $$.

Therefore $F$ is neither even nor odd.